# How can I break a batch script that is executing a ping without terminating the whole script?

Tags: batch, script, cmd.exe, ping

I have a batch script that continuously pings an address and I want a way to cancel the pinging but not terminate the whole script (alternative to ctrl^C).

Comment: use the `.bat` equivalent of an `if\elif\else` statement, `while` loop, `for` loop, the list and possibilities go on and on.

http://ss64.com/nt/if.html or http://jpsoft.com/help/do.htm

Answer (score 2):

Simple. You use CTRL-C as you normally would.

When you do this inside a batch script, you'll get a question `^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)?`

If you enter a N here, the ping ends, but the batchfile continues.

Comment: My problem was that once I entered N, it ended the ping but since I had a loop command it kept restarting the ping. So I simply added a command the the beginning of the script so that I had control over the loop continuing or not. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, but your question did not mention that, so I couldn't know. :)

Comment: No worries, you still made me realize that it would end the ping it's just a matter of what it does next

Comment: If my answer helped you, feel free to accept it. The answer is correct to your question anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-n` switch of `ping` to specify the amount of requests to send or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>to pause to see statistics without terminating the command.